# SSIS: How to handle exceptions while importing data

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

In this scenario I am dealing with very huge excel files (~150 MB) which have multiple but unknown number of sheets (We know them to be less than 20). The number of these sheets depend on the number of records in the excel file; once a sheet is filled to its max records (1,048,576 rows), another is created.
I would like to use SSIS to import all the data in these files into SQL Server tables.

Before, instead of using SSIS, we had a stored procedure to read the excel file using OpenRowset, import the data on 1st sheet and if it had passed the hard limit, the new sheet name is tested. The approach is not very optimized, as it calls upon Microsoft ACE OLEDB (Or ancient Microsoft Jet Provider) which are very, very slow compared to bulk insert.

Importing excel data using SSIS seems much faster in case of simple excel files. Trying to extract sheet names seems to need to treat the file as Rowset collections and will slow down the process. My suggested approach is to use an outer "Foreach Loop" to handle my excel files and an inner "For Loop" to handle worksheets within each file. Once the next worksheet is called and does not exist, the for loop should break but the outer loop should crunch the next file. (something similar to try/catch block)

My question is: is it possible? if yes, how?

(We have an alternative solution to use CLR to convert the excel file into csv files and then import the data, but we would like to keep the job within SSIS package if possible.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Looping files in SSIS is easy, looking worksheets in an Excel file not so much; you'll need to use a script task to inspect the file and get the names of all the sheets to create an object to loop through. There are, however, plenty of articles and tutorials on such tasks; you're not the first person to want to do this nor the last. What about those articles/tutorials didn't you understand? Where did you get up to and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hi @Larnu, the whole idea was trying "not" to access the excel file by treating it as Rowset collection as I have mentioned before. It is quite easy to loop through worksheets if you work it up using MS ACE OLEDB provider. but this approach is painfully slow for very big files like the one in my case. Here I am trying to try (guess) worksheet names without really knowing them and recover on error.
As for guides, I think you mean something like this, which is really useful:
https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2531/loop-over-excel-worksheets.htm